# Libreoffice online with owncloud

Tags: libreoffice, owncloud

I am trying to set up the experimental libreoffice online with owncloud. The only resource I found is this https://owncloud.org/blog/libreoffice-online-has-arrived-in-owncloud/ and the therein (implicitly) mentioned README file https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/online/tree/README

I have a working owncloud installation and I managed to compile the libreoffice components. The next hint is this page: https://github.com/owncloud/richdocuments (also mentioned in the first link).

How do I make libreoffice accessible in owncloud?

Answer (score 0):

well I think this solution is quite updated since the office that maintains the owncloud community is made in javascript and at the moment it is good for the management of trades:
https://owncloud.com/collabora/
https://github.com/owncloud/richdocuments

Comment: Welcome to Super User and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful (especially when one of them is already referenced in the question). Instead, could you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1500439/edit) your answer to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.